# Tried loading Skype and it says I can't

Tags: skype

I tried loading Skype and I kept I am told it can't install 'libasound2:i386' not sure whats going on any suggestions?

Comment: Can you include the exact error message you are getting, as well as the version of Ubuntu you are using?

Comment: sure I am using the latest version 12.04LTS 64bit as far as the error not sure that was all it said was 'cannot install 'libasound2:i386'

Comment: I got the message when I tried to install right off the Skype page.

Comment: Just type `sudo apt-get install skype` in a terminal or in the Ubuntu Software Center. The version of skype included in the main site is rubrish.

Comment: hmmm. Received this message   'reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package skype

Comment: Can you try and do `sudo apt-get install libasound2:i386` and see what it says?

Comment: @ThomasW. it is. Check Nade's answer.

Comment: Ya I just wasn't sure if he had the partner repository enabled. So I said he should add it.

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal and enter

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

then click enter to confirm

then enter

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype
```

Skype is available in the partner repositories.

```
apt-cache policy skype
skype:
  Installed: 4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
  Candidate: 4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 0
        500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ raring/partner amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the update first, then install the two 32 bit compatibility libraries, then try the skype again

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs ia32-libs-multiarch:i386
sudo apt-get install skype
```